# How to store the variable of an asynchronous callback function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am developing a chrome extension and I am trying to output the selected text on the tab in a textarea inside the plugin.

The function to get the selected text works very well but I can't set the value to the textarea element inside the plugin.

**Question:** How do I correctly store the value to be able to then pass it to the textarea with data-binding?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>Here will appear the selected text :</p>
    <textarea name="selectedText" id="selectedText" [(ngModel)]="selectedText"></textarea>
    <button (click)="getSelectedText()">Get the selected text</button>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
export class CaptureComponent {
    selectedText = '';

    getSelectedText() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
            code: 'window.getSelection().toString();'
        }, function(selection) {
            this.selectedText = selection[0];
        });
    }
}
```

The `selection[0]` is working fine so I guess that the way I am trying to store the data is not correct, but I can't seem to find what to change it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current approach, `this` does not refer to your component.

Change your callback to use an arrow function to keep the scope:

```
getSelectedText() {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
     code: 'window.getSelection().toString();'
     }, (selection) => {
       this.selectedText = selection[0];
    });
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but my value is only updated the second time I execute the function. Do you have an idea why and how to prevent it?

Comment: Weird, are you sure it isn't simply taking a long time to execute the first time?

Comment: Yes, I can wait 20 seconds after the first time and still nothing, but it will always be immediate after the second time

Comment: Maybe `selection[0]` is empty the first time you execute the function? What do you get if you print to the console?

Comment: No, if I print selection[0] inside the function(after setting it to this.selectedText), it already has a value the first time I execute the function. It looks like a chrome problem because if I execute a completely unrelated function it kind of "refreshes" the values and the text appears in the textarea